# Two tables and count(*) in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, count, eloquent

I have two tables with posts and votes. How to tell laravel to count votes from 'votes' table and join it with posts table by id?

I have raw query like:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) FROM votes WHERE posts.id = votes.post_id) AS votes FROM posts 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

But then I cannot use `$query->pagination(6)` with I need.

After in blade I want to just user something like that:
`{{ $posts->votes }}` where votes is number of rows in 'votes' table with the same id as post.

Comment: do you have any model relationships set up?  Then you could do it easily by getting a Post (whether it be in a foreach or a Post::find, etc) and doing $post->votes()->count();

Answer (score 0):

I had this same need and used a trait to create the subqueries.

I got the idea here.
https://github.com/anlutro/laravel-4-core/blob/master/src/ModelTraits/WithRelationCount.php